# resolving CS0246 error on Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, compiler-errors

I recently changed the root namespace for my ASP.NET MVC project now when I run the project I get CS0246 error on accessing the default controller view. Home/Index. Its complaining about a use statement for the old namespace.

using Web;

but should be

using GotIt.Web;

Comment: I usually just do a Find All (Ctrl-Shift-F) for "using Web", select Entire Solution and turn off case and whole word sensitivity.  Then it should be a simple matter to change them to the new name.

Answer (score 1):

When refactoring the namespace of an ASP.NET MVC project you must manually update the Views\web.config   section.

CHANGE

```
 <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="Web" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

TO

```
 <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="GotIt.Web" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: Only if you are using that namespace in your views.